# PHP GET запрос на другой файл

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть файл который принимает GET запрос, и обрабатывает его делая определенные действия.

Сейчас структура сайта немного изменилась, и есть возможность сделать include этого файла в момент выполнения действия.

Так вот, я хотел бы узнать, как правильнее сделать. Оставить ту же структуру, объявить к примеру $_GET['var'] = 1,  и сделать include файла который обрабатывает эту переменную.

Или отослать GET запрос на тот же файл, с текущего php файла? Спасибо

Comment: я сижу за столом и у меня есть бутерброд. как вы думаете, мне его лучше просто взять и съесть, или выкинуть в окно, сходить за ним, а потом съесть? во втором случае, правда придется покинуть здание, потерять время, и нужно будет еще раз помыть руки.

Comment: никто вам тут однозначного ответа не даст, ибо не знает картины в общем. Если отдельный этот файл это другой сервис, с АПИ, к примеру, то обращаться к нему надо как к апи, то есть оставить запрос. Если это файл из вашего же проекта, и инклуд кажется логичным, то сделайте это. Однако, рассмотрите варианты внедрения ООП. Чтобы не сам скприт выполнял действия, а предоставлял классы которые это делают.  В таком случе использование такого класса в нескольких местах кажется куда более логичным

Comment: а отправляя новый запрос, вы теряете контекст текущего, сессию и т.п. если это важно, и получаете задержки по времени

Comment: @teran я вас понял, спасибо